# Vuejs Grid с Постраничным разделением (пагинация)

Tags: vue.js, постраничный-вывод

Есть [Grid](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xkkbfL3L/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=xkkbfL3L) из официального примера:
Как к нему можно сделать "постраничное разделение"?
Данных всегда может быть разное количество.

```
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var data = this.data
      if (filterKey) {
        data = data.filter(function (row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        data = data.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return data
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function (str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 }
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариант @OlegShleif адаптированный на vue2:

```js
// register the grid component
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String,
    rowsPerPage: Number
  },
  data: function() {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function(key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders,
      startRow: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function() {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var data = this.data

      this.startRow = 0 // reset to start

      if (filterKey) {
        data = data.filter(function(row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function(key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        data = data.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return data
    },
    dataPerPage: function() {
      return this.filteredData.filter((item, index) => index >= this.startRow && index < (this.startRow + this.rowsPerPage))
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function(str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function(key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    },
    movePages: function(amount) {
      var newStartRow = this.startRow + (amount * this.rowsPerPage);
      if (newStartRow >= 0 && newStartRow < this.filteredData.length) {
        this.startRow = newStartRow;
      }
    }
  }
})

var baseData = [{
  name: 'Chuck Norris',
  power: Infinity
}, {
  name: 'Bruce Lee',
  power: 9000
}, {
  name: 'Jackie Chan',
  power: 7000
}, {
  name: 'Jet Li',
  power: 8000
}];
var gridData = Array(100).fill(null).map(function() {
  return Object.assign({}, baseData[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
});

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: gridData
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

th,
td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}

#page-navigation {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#page-navigation p {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#page-navigation button {
  background-color: #42b983;
  border-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th v-for="key in columns" @click="sortBy(key)" :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
            {{ key | capitalize }}
            <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="entry in dataPerPage">
          <td v-for="key in columns">
            {{entry[key]}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="page-navigation">
      <button @click=movePages(-1)>Back</button>
      <p>{{startRow / rowsPerPage + 1}} out of {{Math.ceil(filteredData.length / rowsPerPage)}}</p>
      <button @click=movePages(1)>Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid :data="gridData" :columns="gridColumns" :filter-key="searchQuery" :rows-per-page="10">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем примере, сильно меняется структура... можно ли минимальными правками, такими как пример  @OlegShleif  осуществить это с vue2?

Comment: Поправил, взял за основу grid из шапки, структуру не менял, только пагинация и vue2.

Comment: Выдает ошибку .  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.MOver_PROVIDERS (translator.js:144)
MOver_PROVIDERS @ translator.js:144
translator.js:151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.MOut_PROVIDERS (translator.js:151)
MOut_PROVIDERS @ translator.js:151

Comment: Где запускаете? У меня все в порядке, запускаю в хром, кнопка выполнить код

Comment: В Google chrome запускаю

Comment: Не знаю, что сказать, попробуйте перенести код в codepen/jsfiddle. Судя по ошибке, она к vue отношения не имеет. Может какие-то расширения браузера влияют.

Comment: Да, проблема была в браузере, откатился на более позднюю версию google chrome все работает. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день Евгений, вот вам [пример с пагинацией](http://jsfiddle.net/ctlevi/xbarpj1L/)

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="key in columns">
        {{key | capitalize}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="entry in data | limitBy rowsPerPage startRow">
      <td v-for="key in columns">
        {{entry[key]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="page-navigation">
  <button @click=movePages(-1)>Back</button>
  <p>{{startRow / rowsPerPage + 1}} out of {{Math.ceil(data.length / rowsPerPage)}}</p>
  <button @click=movePages(1)>Next</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var baseData = [{
  name: 'Chuck Norris',
  power: Infinity
}, {
  name: 'Bruce Lee',
  power: 9000
}, {
  name: 'Jackie Chan',
  power: 7000
}, {
  name: 'Jet Li',
  power: 8000
}];
var gridData = Array(100).fill(null).map(function() {
  return Object.assign({}, baseData[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
});

// register the grid component
Vue.component('grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    movePages: Function,
    startRow: Number,
    rowsPerPage: Number
  }
});

// Create the view-model
var gridViewModel = new Vue({
  el: '#grid-view-model',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: gridData,
    startRow: 0,
    rowsPerPage: 10
  },
  methods: {
    movePages: function(amount) {
      var newStartRow = this.startRow + (amount * this.rowsPerPage);
      if (newStartRow >= 0 && newStartRow < gridData.length) {
        this.startRow = newStartRow;
      }
    },
    resetStartRow: function() {
      this.startRow = 0;
    }
  },
  filters: {
    orderByBusinessRules: function(data) {
      return data.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.power - b.power;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: спасибо.   
А можно, что-бы при этом несмотря на какой странице ты находишься поиск бы искал по всей и выводил результат на этой станице?

Comment: Исправил ссылку и код

Comment: Вы использовали  Vue.js v1.0.26 на Vue.js v2 не работает данный пример.